# WPF Application - Visual Studio 2008 Toolbox Not Loading Correctly!

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2008, wpf-controls

I'm pretty new to WPF however i've got a solid understanding of WindowsForms. When I create a new WinForms application in Visual Studio the Toolbox displays a huge list of different controls that can be used for developing the program.

However, this is only the second time i've started to design stuff in WPF and the toolbox is literally only showing a few of the common controls - things like text boxes and buttons and not much else.

I've create a WPF app before in which i dragged a flow document onto the grid and played around with its capabilities, but that doesn't seem to be there.

No idea why this is happening?
Something not loading correctly?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reset the toolbox to its original state using the [Choose Toolbox Items Dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dyca0t6t.aspx).

Be aware, though - WPF has far fewer controls in the Toolbox than Windows Forms.  By default, there will not be many controls available, especially if you're comparing it against a windows forms control/form.

Answer (score 1):

Go to tools -> Import and Export settings -> Wizard will be opened choose **Import selected environment setting** click next you will find sth similar to this

C:\Documents and Settings\deepak.kumar2\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Settings\VWD Express

A file will be selected by default, change this file either in **VWD Express** folder or in **Settings** folder

this name will be sth like **CurrentSettings.vssettings** now click next and close

now go to tools-> Choose toolbox items -> select **WPF Component** tab now choose any control from the available list

Deepak Kalra

Answer (score 0):

I had problems once with VS2008 not showing toolbox items. Although my problem wasn't related to WPF, the solution I found might be useful - what I did was to start Visual Studio through command line, using an option to reset skip packages during load.

From VS command prompt:

```
devenv.exe /resetskippkgs
```